# MySQL query in nodejs need to be sequential executed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mysql-connector

Rather new to nodejs, coming from php space. A question about the async behavior for MySQL query.

I need to make some query, and then depends on the query result, and make further sequential action. I know I can solved by callback function. But as it need i need to do quite a number of sequential action. If keep on using callback function, might make the code difficult to read.

I wrote the below code. I expect the "BBB" will be print out after connected, and the console.log(r1) will be print out the type of r1 (but now it is undefined, i think it is executed before the mysql connect).

May I know how should I write so that "BBB" will be print out only after the connect is completed?

Or would there be other mysql library i can use? Many thanks

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const axios = require('axios')

const mysqlHost = process.env.DB_SERVER;
const mysqlUser = process.env.DB_USER;
const mysqlPassword = process.env.DB_PWD;
const mysqlDatabase = process.env.DB_DATABASE;


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : mysqlHost,
  user     : mysqlUser,
  password : mysqlPassword,
  database : mysqlDatabase,
});

(async () => {  
  const r1 = await con.connect(function(err) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      console.log("Connected!");
                    });
                    console.log(typeof r1); // output is undefined
                    console.log("BBB") 
  const r2 = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
  //console.log(r2);
})()
console.log("This message come out the 1st. Perfect!")

con.end();
```